# Convert string from args/flags to json then send to post http request as body

Tags: http, go, post

I'm trying to pass the values ​​I get in the arg / flag **--BODY="{user: root}"** as the body of the post request I'm trying to do, I've already used json.Marshal and even so I wasn't successful, thanks for the help !

***Code below:***

```
func Custom(method string, url string, token string, data string) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(data))

    req.Header.Add("Authorization", FormatBearerToken(token))
    // req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Request failed, ", err)
    }

    client := &http.Client{}

    resp, err := client.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    log.Println("response Body:", string(body))
}
```

Comment: If the body of the post is supposed to be a JSON document, it is not valid. You have to double-quote the key and the value.

Comment: oh thanks, but even if i double quote the body, should i do something more to make it work? like parse to byte or something like that

Comment: I don't know the API you're calling, so I can't say. Start by sending a valid JSON document and go from there

Comment: my api its accepting any type of json, im just trying to make the body reachs there, but thanks, im gonna keep trying!

Comment: `json.Marshal` will work on `struct`